# Aligning grid lines to axis ticks in lattice graphics

Tags: r, lattice

Is there a way to align grid lines if they are chosen custom?
By default, panel.grid(h=-1,v=-1) does the job, but I'd like to refine the grid according to the axis ticks. Setting h and v to negative lengths of axis ticks doesn't always work.

Update: Below is an example. I would like to achieve that horizontal grid lines match the y-axis ticks. Currently half of horizontal grid lines are missing.

```
library(lattice)

G <- cut(trees$Girth, seq(8, 22, by = 3))
p <- xyplot(Height ~ Volume | G, data = trees,
          scales = list(x = list(alternating = 3, at = seq(10, 60, by = 5)),
                        y = list(alternating = 3, at = seq(65, 85, by = 2.5))),
          panel = function(x, y, ...){
              panel.grid(v = -11, h = -9)
              panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)})
print(p)
```

What I currently get is this:

[image]

Comment: Post a sample problem and code to build the lattice plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want ticks and grid lines at places other than those returned by `pretty`, then don't use `panel.grid`; instead use `panel.abline`, with your custom `at` sequences.

```
library(lattice)

G <- cut(trees$Girth, seq(8, 22, by = 3))
x.at = 5*(2:12)
y.at = 2.5*(26:34)
p <- xyplot(Height ~ Volume | G, data = trees,
          scales = list(x = list(alternating = 3, at = x.at),
                        y = list(alternating = 3, at = y.at)),
          panel = function(x, y, ...){
              panel.abline(v = x.at, h = y.at, col="lightgrey")
              panel.xyplot(x, y, ...)})
print(p)
```

And don't forget to set the colour to something suitably light.

[image]

The limitation with `panel.grid` is mentioned deep down in `help(panel.grid)`:

> **h, v**
>   For panel.abline, these are numeric vectors giving locations respectively of horizontal and vertical 
>   lines to be added to the plot, in native coordinates.
>
> For panel.grid, these usually specify the number of horizontal and
>   vertical reference lines to be added to the plot. Alternatively, they
>   can be negative numbers. h=-1 and v=-1 are intended to make the grids
>   aligned with the axis labels. *This doesn't always work*; all that
>   actually happens is that the locations are chosen using pretty, which
>   is also how the label positions are chosen in the most common cases
>   (but not for factor variables, for instance). h and v can be negative
>   numbers other than -1, in which case -h and -v (as appropriate) is
>   supplied as the n argument to pretty.

(My italics for emphasis).

**One more wrinkle**

If you have applied a transformation to an axis with a `scale` list, you have to apply the same transformation to the `at` vector that you supply to `panel.abline` - I don't know how to get this to happen automatically.