# R lattice xyplot doesn't match grid to axes' ticks (not multiplot)

Tags: r, plot, lattice, logarithm, r-grid

I'm trying to produce a plot with lattice's xyplot by the following code:

```
set.seed(123) #### make it reproducible
df<-data.frame(x=runif(100,1,1e7),y=runif(100,0.01,.08),t=as.factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=T)))
png("xyplot_grid_misaligned.png",800,800)
p<-xyplot(y ~ x,groups=t,data=df,scales=list(x=list(log=10,equispaced.log=F)),auto.key=T,ylim=c(-.01,.1),grid=T)
print(p)
dev.off()
```

It produces, as expected, a beautiful plot:
[image: xyplot with grid misaligned]

I'd like the grid on the plot to be aligned with the tick marks generated by `equispaced.log=F`. The documentation of xyplot only discusses `grid` in relation to multiple plots, as do some other threads in SO and other sites (In fact, I got the `grid=T` argumment from another site: [Using Lattice graphics in R](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~jenny/STAT545A/block09_xyplotLattice.html), and even there you can see that when `equispaced.log=F` is used, the grid "misaligns" with the ticks).

Just in case someone might think this is a duplicate of [SO: aligning-grid-lines-to-axis-ticks-in-lattice-graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433227/aligning-grid-lines-to-axis-ticks-in-lattice-graphics), please notice that the question in there was how to align the grids in a multiplot (and, at the time, the thread has no answer yet).

How can I have xyplot "aligning" grid lines to x ticks while using **`equispaced.log=F`**?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you need to use a custom panel function to do this, and to use `panel.abline` instead of `panel.grid`.  The best I could come up with is to set the tick points semi-manually.

```
library(lattice)
set.seed(123) #### make it reproducible

df<-data.frame(x=runif(100,1,1e7),y=runif(100,0.01,.08),t=as.factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=T)))

# do this one by hand, since you had "equispaced.log=F"
x.at = c(5e3, 10e3, 5e4, 10e4, 5e5, 10e5, 5e6, 10e6)
# but this one is done with `pretty` as usual
y.at = pretty(df$y,4)

png("xyplot_grid_aligned.png",600,600)
p <- xyplot(y ~ x,groups=t,data=df,
            scales=list(x=list(at=x.at,log=10),
                        y=list(at=y.at)),
            auto.key=T,
            ylim=c(-.01,.1),
            panel = function(...) {
                panel.abline(v=log10(x.at),h=y.at,col="lightgrey")
                panel.xyplot(...)
            }
            )
print(p)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Thruston, it definitely is what I needed at the time, surely I'll use it in the future. I wonder if I can turn yours as the "real" answer, as it silves it with lattice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a ggplot solution, if that's helpful.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=t)) +
  geom_point(shape=21) + 
  scale_x_log10(breaks=c(5e3, 1e4, 5e4,1e5,5e5,1e6,5e6,1e7)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it is helpful indeed, I just would like to know if it's at all possible in lattice.