# R: Four Lattice barcharts side-by-side in 2x2 Window?

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart, lattice

Code where I would like to do 2x2 barcharts side-by-side such that the y-axis max value would be the same in all and

- common ylabel
- common xlabel
- common legends
- common title
- each barchart with their own subtitle
- separator line between each barchart like in Fig. 2

Code

```
# Wanted output 2x2 barchart where top column Ite. 1 and Ite. 2 and row-names female and male
# http://www.magesblog.com/2012/12/changing-colours-and-legends-in-lattice.html

require("lattice")

f<-function(x) as.double(as.character(x))   #factors converted to vectors http://stackoverflow.com/a/40680020/54964

data.female <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", 
"1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"), N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"), N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"), N44.1 = structure(2:3, .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"), N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"), N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"), N32.1 = structure(c(5L, 
7L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", 
"22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", "44.0", "N32"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", 
"N22.1", "N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"), row.names = c("Sinus", 
"Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")

data.male <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", 
"1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"), N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"), N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"), N44.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"), 
    N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"), 
    N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"), 
    N32.1 = structure(c(11L, 9L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", 
    "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", "22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", 
    "44.0", "N32"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", "N22.1", 
"N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"), row.names = c("Sinus", 
"Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")

ID<-c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")

tl <- "female"
barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.female,
         auto.key=list(space='right'), 
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl
         )
tl <- "male"
barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.male,
         auto.key=list(space='right'),
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl 
         )

# Just repeat two barcharts more to get 2x2 example
tl <- "female"
barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.female,
         auto.key=list(space='right'), 
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl
         )
tl <- "male"
barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.male,
         auto.key=list(space='right'),
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl 
         )
```

Fig. 1 Current output separate, 
Fig. 2 Wanted output structure, 
Fig. 3 User 20650 barchart code output

[image]
[image]
[image]

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: facet_wrap() will be of help

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814478/ggplot2-multiple-plots-in-a-single-row-with-a-single-legend

Comment: @akrun How do you apply `facet_wrap(~ variable, scales = "free")` here? Is `melt` required?

Comment: Why do you import ggplot2 when you use only lattice?

Comment: The other comments are related to ggplot2 package but your example concerns only Lattice package so the comments are irrelevant to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this by reshaping your data

First sort out the class of the variables and add grouping variables

```
# convert type and add gender label
# I would have a look at why your numerics have been stored as factors
data.female[] <- lapply(data.female, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
data.female$gender <- "female"
data.female$ID <- rownames(data.female)

data.male[] <- lapply(data.male, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
data.male$gender <- "male"
data.male$ID <- rownames(data.male)
```

bind the two data frames together

```
dat <- rbind(data.female[names(data.male)], data.male)
```

Arrange data for plotting

```
library(reshape2)
datm <- melt(dat)
```

Plot

```
# Lattice
library(lattice)
barchart(variable ~ value|ID, groups=gender, data=datm,
                               auto.key=list(space='right'))

# ggplot2
ggplot(datm, aes(variable, value, fill=gender)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge()) +
  facet_grid(ID ~ .)
```

Comment: Yes, just rearrange the data, and add labels as required. (note that the reason your *wanted output* is 2x2 is that the grouping variable (in your question , the ID variable) has four levels)

Comment: if you want a 2x2 you need either the grouping variable to have more than two levels, or an additional variable to group on.  This uses the second, eg `dat <- rbind(data.female[names(data.male)], data.female[names(data.male)], data.male, data.male) ;
dat$othergroupingvariable <- rep(c("A", "B"), each=2) ;
datm <- melt(dat, id=c("ID", "gender", "othergroupingvariable"));
barchart(variable ~ value|ID+othergroupingvariable, groups=gender, data=datm,  auto.key=list(space='right'))`

Comment: Works! Is it normal not to start the barchart from negative? - - My some columns are zero but the typical way shows little negativity to show them. - - Is there any good way here to add grids? - - There is also a dummy `.1` after each column name, which origin, I do not understand. In my data, I do not see it. How can it be removed from the barcharts?

Comment: yeah, that starting elow zero is weird. You can set `origin=0` but this still shows a line for the zeros, and is certainly not optimal. Id suggest you have a look on the www as this must have been asked before. gridlines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433227/aligning-grid-lines-to-axis-ticks-in-lattice-graphics

Comment: The`.1` are after are the names of the columns of the data you provide in your question. `names(data.male)`: [1] "N11.1"  "N22.1"  "N33.1"  "N44.1"  "N21.1"  "N31.1"  "N32.1"

Comment: look at the data in your question and you can see the names end with `.1`. This is before any lapply or other transforms. So it is happening at your end in your code.

Comment: I expanded the case here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40694522/54964 with my real data as .CSV files because I cannot see any source `.1`. I also want to expand 2x2 barchart to 2x4.

Answer (score 2):

You are using Lattice PKG that depends on grid PKG so you need to use windowing of Grid PKG as instructed in [Lattice: multiple plots in one window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540129/lattice-multiple-plots-in-one-window). The ggplot2 is never used in the code. You can do the 2x2 window with `grid.arrange` command.

**Grid.arrange with GridExtras package and Lattice package**

[image]

```
require(lattice)
require(gridExtra)

f<-function(x) as.double(as.character(x))   #factors converted to vectors https://stackoverflow.com/a/40680020/54964

data.female <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", 
"1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"), N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"), N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"), N44.1 = structure(2:3, .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"), N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"), N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"), N32.1 = structure(c(5L, 
7L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", 
"22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", "44.0", "N32"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", 
"N22.1", "N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"), row.names = c("Sinus", 
"Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")

data.male <- structure(list(N11.1 = structure(c(3L, 3L), .Label = c("", "0.0", 
"1.0", "N11"), class = "factor"), N22.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", 
"0.0", "2.0", "N22"), class = "factor"), N33.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N33"), class = "factor"), N44.1 = structure(c(2L, 
2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "0.1", "0.2", "N44"), class = "factor"), 
    N21.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N21"), class = "factor"), 
    N31.1 = structure(c(2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "N31"), class = "factor"), 
    N32.1 = structure(c(11L, 9L), .Label = c("", "0.0", "10.8", 
    "11.0", "12.0", "17.0", "20.9", "22.8", "24.0", "3.0", "4.0", 
    "44.0", "N32"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("N11.1", "N22.1", 
"N33.1", "N44.1", "N21.1", "N31.1", "N32.1"), row.names = c("Sinus", 
"Arr/AHB"), class = "data.frame")

ID<-c("Sinus","Arr/AHB")

tl <- "female"
p1 <- barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.female,
         auto.key=list(space='right'), 
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl
         )
tl <- "male"
p2 <- barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.male,
         auto.key=list(space='right'),
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl 
         )

# Just repeat two barcharts more to get 2x2 example
tl <- "female"
p3 <- barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.female,
         auto.key=list(space='right'), 
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl
         )
tl <- "male"
p4 <- barchart(f(N11.1)+f(N22.1)+f(N33.1)+f(N44.1)+f(N21.1)+f(N31.1)+f(N32.1) ~ ID,
         data=data.male,
         auto.key=list(space='right'),
         ylim=c(0,50),
     beside=TRUE,
     ylab = "Number of cases", 
     xlab = "Population/Sample",
     main = tl)




grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, nrow=2)
```

as for the common xlabel, ylabel and so on, change the last line to

```
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4, ncol=2, nrow=2,left=("LEFT TITLE"),right=("RIGHT"),bottom=("BOTTOM"), top=("TOP"))
```

[image]

*P.s. I moved the last puzzle about the shared legend [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699787/r-shared-legend-from-a-subplot-to-the-2x2-grid-arrange-panel-with-lattice).*

Comment: @Masi this is addressed to some extent [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11076567/plot-a-legend-and-well-spaced-universal-y-axis-and-main-titles-in-grid-arrange), alert they use ggplot2 there.

Comment: Common legends?

Comment: I cannot apply `legend = gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(p1), "guide-box")`.

Comment: @Masi of course not, you need to create a solution using lattice and grid, perhaps more relevant question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33346823/global-legend-using-grid-arrange-gridextra-and-lattice-based-plots).